# Getting bison parser to divulge debug information

Tags: parsing, bison

I am having trouble writing a bison parser, and unexpectedly ran into difficulties getting the parser to print debug information. I found two solutions on the web, but neither seems to work.

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=516658) advocates to put this code in the main routine:

```
extern int yydebug;
yydebug = 1;
```

Unfortunately the C++ compiler detects an undefined reference to `yydebug'.

[This](http://faculty.rmc.edu/jrabung/csc.411/parser.htm) suggests putting

```
        #if YYDEBUG == 1
           extern yydebug;
           yydebug = 1;
        #endif
```

into the grammar file. It compiles but does not produce output.

What does work is to edit the parser file itself, replacing

```
int yydebug;
```

by

```
int yydebug = 1;
```

The big disadvantage is that I have to redo this every time I change the grammar file, which during debugging would happen constantly. Is there any other way I can provoke the parser into coughing up its secret machinations?

I am using bison v2.4.1 to generate the parser, with the following command-line options:

```
bison -ldv -p osil -o $(srcdir)/OSParseosil.tab.cpp OSParseosil.y
```

Although the output is a C++ file, I am using the standard C skeleton.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you feel it necessary to suppress `#line` directives using the `-l` flag?

Comment: "Monkey see, monkey do". I inherited this line from somewhere, and stuck to it for sheer life. (I didn't even now what it was good for.)

Comment: So change the l to t and debugging is compiled in :) The prefix is the source of your problem; see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bison` and the standard C skeleton, to enable debug support you need to do one of the following:

- Use the `-t` (Posix) or `--debug` (Bison extension) command-line option when you create your grammar. (`bison -t ...`)
- Use the `-DYYDEBUG=1` command-line option (gcc or clang, at least) when you compile the generated grammar (`gcc -DYYDEBUG=1` parser.tab.c ...`).
- Add the `%debug` directive to your bison source
- Put `#define YYDEBUG 1` in the prologue in your bison source (the part of the file between `%{` and `%}`.

I'd use `-t` in the bison command line. It's simple, and since it is Posix standard it *probably* will also work on other derived parser generators. However, adding `%debug` to the bison source is also simple; while it is not as portable, it works in bison 2.4.

Once you've done that, simply setting `yydebug` to a non-zero value is sufficient to produce debug output.

If you want to set `yydebug` in some translation unit other than the generated parser itself, you need to be aware of the parser prefix you declared in the `bison` command line. (In the parser itself, `yydebug` is `#define`d to the prefixed name.) And you need to declare the debug variable (with the correct prefix) as extern. So in your main, you probably want to use:

```
extern int osildebug;
// ...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  osildebug = 1;
  // ...
}
```

---

If you're using `bison`, your best place to find information is the [`bison manual`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Enabling-Traces.html#Enabling-Traces); most of the above answer will be found in that page.

Comment: I use the fourth option, `#define YYDEBUG 1`. The code is part of a large system, and I'd rather not mess with the makefiles. But, as my question indicates, `extern int yydebug` does not seem to work for me. The compiler does not accept `yydebug` as a valid symbol. As to bison vs. bisonc++: I use bison v.2.4.1 in order to produce c++ code. Guess I don't quite understand the use of the bisonc++ tag.

Comment: Where do you put the `#define`? If you use it correctly, then the `yydebug` variable should be available. (The `bisonc++` tag should be used if you are using the parser generator called `bisonc++`. For bison, use bison.)

Comment: The `#define` directive is in the prologue of my parser source.

Comment: @user3697176: Ok, I tried it with bison 2.4.2 using `--skeleton=lalr1.cc` to generate a C++ parser. And it turns out that the generated parser doesn't have a `yydebug` at all. It has a `yydebug_`, but that is a private member variable. So... could you be even more specific about how you are invoking bison?

Comment: Here are the commands from the makefile:
`flex  -Posil -o$(srcdir)/OSParseosil.cpp  $(srcdir)/OSParseosil.l`
`bison -ldv -p osil -o $(srcdir)/OSParseosil.tab.cpp OSParseosil.y`

Comment: @user3697176: I'm going to edit that into your question, because it is extremely relevant. Unless you beat me to it.

Comment: @rici There's a set_debug_level method for the C++ parser which is where yydebug_ is set. Invoke it with value 1 and you ought to have debug messages enabled given you've done one of the four ways of enabling debug traces.

Comment: @fernal: if you use bison's c++ template. OP indicated the use of the c template. But that's useful information, too

Comment: Yes, I seem to have misread your comment. It would be nice to have better insight into how the C++ versions work.

Comment: @fernal: the bison team is constantly improving the documentation, and I have the sense that the C++ template is important to them. I don't use it much myself, though. I'm happy to try to field questions, but it's always good to start by reading the manual.

Comment: Agreed. My point is that most examples are in C. And the difficulty is in integrating the c++ versions of both flex and bison.

Comment: @fernal73: If you've got something working which does that, you should post it. If you have a specific issue, please post it as a question. (No promises that it will get a good answer, but we do try.) It seems like a useful project. Documentation has never been OSS's strong point, but the old "patches welcome" advice still applies, IMHO. :-)

Comment: https://learnmoderncpp.com/2020/12/16/generating-c-programs-with-flex-and-bison-1/ is a nice piece of work that demonstrates the working of flex and bison using their C++ classes.